# magento performance

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I am new in Magento. Can we make the magento cms as framework independent. Any fastest framework can be replaced with the base framework of magento. For example phalcon (fastest framework) should be replaced by zend framework, so that magento gives best performance, or can be make the whole zend framework as extension and all framework already loaded in memory.

Answer (score 5):

You dont simply change a framework, also its not the framework itself which makes everything slow but the number of festures you have and use.

Also what you dont keep in mind is development speed, another framework could increase development time a lot in the long run, which is most time the bigger expense then having just more or bigger servers. Interestingly the price to power relation improves a lot more then the price to development relation which should bring you to the actual conclusion we need easier frameworks, instead of faster ones.

Comment: The most important factor is speed. Everything is manageable except speed. If we configure the magento cms for all frameworks or any fast framework then we can easily integrate any framework. We can share data through apis.

Comment: If you only need speed, you should just create another online shop system in a compiled language.